# Stats.txt in gem5 is always 0 Bytes

Tags: gem5

I compiled a higher version of the kernel.

The program data that was eventually run in fs mode is not written to stats.txt.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to provide more detail, or else it is unlikely that you will get any help: gem5 version, full gem5 command line, linux version and config, stdout and `m5out/system.terminal`. The only way I can see for this to happen is the kernel is not booting, did you check that? Here is a working Linux v4.18 setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/83b36867cf06ffdca3ce04296a8568d4f37ea13b#gem5-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Gem5 is the latest version

ubuntu-14.04

build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=linux-x86.img --kernel=/home/jiaotong/gem5/gem5-NUCA-master/fs-image/binaries/vmlinux

The kernel is a 3.2.24 kernel compiled with the configuration file of the official website 2.6.28.4.

this is system.terminal：
Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0

Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset

Linux version 3.14.0 (sim@openstack1) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 15 16:33:56 CST 2016

Kernel was built at commit id 'b2af788'

CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc0f0] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d

CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache

Machine model: V2P-CA15

bootconsole [earlycon0] enabled

Memory policy: Data cache writealloc

kdebugv2m: Following are test values to confirm proper working

kdebugv2m: Ranges 42000000 0

kdebugv2m: Regs 30000000 1000000

kdebugv2m: Virtual-Reg f0000000

kdebugv2m: pci node addr_cells 3

kdebugv2m: pci node size_cells 2

kdebugv2m: motherboard addr_cells 2

On node 0 totalpages: 131072

free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 80679840, node_mem_map 9fbf9000

Normal zone: 1024 pages used for memmap

Normal zone: 0 pages reserved

Normal zone: 131072 pages, LIFO batch:31

sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 178956969942ns

PERCPU: Embedded 8 pages/cpu @9fbe1000 s12224 r8192 d12352 u32768

pcpu-alloc: s12224 r8192 d12352 u32768 alloc=8*4096

pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1

Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048

Kernel command line: earlyprintk=pl011,0x1c090000 console=ttyAMA0 lpj=19988480 norandmaps rw loglevel=8 mem=512MB root=/dev/sda1

PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)

Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)

Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)